# Not working jQuery easy ticker in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am coding a WordPress template .I want the contents of the proposed I use the jquery easy-ticker.
while Coding this sector, all the loading and I saw that the proposed materials that are writings and photos from top to bottom , on the contrary, it didn't work out and stable . 
This photo :

[image]

The picture that you see are writings from top to bottom and do something like [this.](http://www.aakashweb.com/demos/jquery-easy-ticker/)

Well I I put the code:

```js
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.easy-ticker.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('.iraymond').easyTicker({
            direction: 'up'
        });
    });
</script>
```

```html
<div class="ourpost">
    <h3>مطالب پیشنهادی</h3>
    <div class="iraymond">
        <ul>
            <li><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/2.jpg" alt=""><a href="#">دانلود سیستم محتوای ایرانی آپادانا </a><span>بازدید : 500</span></li>
            <li><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/2.jpg" alt=""><a href="#">دانلود سیستم محتوای ایرانی آپادانا </a><span>بازدید : 500</span></li>
            <li><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/2.jpg" alt=""><a href="#">دانلود سیستم محتوای ایرانی آپادانا </a><span>بازدید : 500</span></li>
            <li><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/2.jpg" alt=""><a href="#">دانلود سیستم محتوای ایرانی آپادانا </a><span>بازدید : 500</span></li>
            <li><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/2.jpg" alt=""><a href="#">دانلود سیستم محتوای ایرانی آپادانا </a><span>بازدید : 500</span></li>
            <li><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/2.jpg" alt=""><a href="#">دانلود سیستم محتوای ایرانی آپادانا </a><span>بازدید : 500</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't know I was wrong Coding or jquery doesn't work … 
Please Check it out, I'd appreciate.

Comment: check browser console for errors, most likely see `$ is undefined` since wordpress uses `noConflict()`. Most likely already have jQuery in page already also. Should use proper methods for enquing scripts as documented in wordpress codex

Comment: the additional $ I deleted but it didn't work .

Comment: That doesn't answer question about errors ... and I have no idea what that even means

Comment: in $('.iraymond').easyTicker({ in browser console warning. $ was also defined but will notice .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, you shouldn't hardcoding your scripts in the template file, but rather [enqueue your scripts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

Try adding this to your `functions.php` file:

```
function my_theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'easyTicker', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.easy-ticker.js', array('jquery'), '2.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-theme-scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my-theme-scripts.js', array('easyTicker'), '1.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_scripts' );
```

And this in a file called `my-theme-scripts.js` inside the `js` folder of your theme:

```
(function($){
    $('.iraymond').easyTicker({
        direction: 'up'
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: The new kinds of coding wordpress ?before It was not that …

Comment: @iraymond not really, it exists since wordpress 2.6.0